# How do I prevent the tkinter wizard format from showing all the pages at once?

Tags: tkinter, wizard

Hopefully I can make this specific enough.  I'm building an app for training on the Laser Cutter at my current place of employment (as some of you have seen in days recent).  I've been able to successfully create a wizard that will walk the trainee through each process, but I've come across a problem with the wizard format.

What happens isn't an error that shows up in the Python Shell, so as far as the interpreter is concerned, there's no problem with the code.  However, when I open the wizard, it wants to display all of the pages at once.  I can click the 'next' and 'previous' buttons and it'll clear up, but I can't finish the fourth page because it'll push the buttons out of the screen and, therefore, out of reach (my screen resolution won't allow for the entire window to fit, and the buttons always start out at the bottom, regardless of assigned position).

If someone could tell me what's causing the issue and how I can fix it, I would greatly appreciate the help.

I've posted the code below.  I only ask for understanding, since this is truthfully the most complex app I've built since the DOS-based calculator I made with C++ a few years back.  In other words, this is my first app with a GUI, and my first app in python.  Therefore, my experience with python, and with stackoverflow for that matter, is very limited.

Please note that some of the modules loaded aren't part of the wizard.  They play a role elsewhere in the app.

```
#Import the Modules required for proper app function
import os, cgi, pickle
from os.path import *
from tkinter import *
import tkinter

#All other windows must be created as Definitions before the Home Screen/Main Menu is coded.
#All Button Commands must be created as Definitions before their respective windows

#Start Code for the Introduction Wizard
def wizIntro():
    wizIntro = tkinter.Tk()

    #Title:
    wizIntro.title('Welcome to Training')

    #Content:
    page1 = Frame(wizIntro)
    Label(page1, text='', width=110).pack()
    Label(page1, text='--Welcome to Training--', width=85).pack()
    Label(page1, text='', width=85).pack()
    Label(page1, text='This tutorial will help you familiarize yourself with the program.  Following it is key to understanding', width=85).pack()
    Label(page1, text='the proper operation of the Laser Cutter.', width=85).pack()
    Label(page1, text='', width=90).pack()
    Label(page1, text='It is also important to follow every insrtuction exactly as stated, to avoid or minimize damage to the Laser', width=85).pack()
    Label(page1, text='Cutter and reduce the risk of injury to the operator and those around him.', width=85).pack()
    Label(page1, text='Therefore, all safety notices must be followed with extreme care.', width=110).pack()
    Label(page1, text='--Failure to follow all safety notices poses a severe risk of damage to the equipment and to the operator, which can be fatal--', width=110, fg='red').pack()
    Label(page1, text='', width=110).pack()
    Label(page1, text='', width=110).pack()
    Label(page1, text='', width=110).pack()
    Label(page1, text='Click Next to Continue...').pack(side = BOTTOM)
    page1.pack()

    page2 = Frame(wizIntro)
    Label(page2, text='', width=110).pack()
    Label(page2, text='Notice:  Before anyone can operate the Laser Cutter, they must have completed this training program and be authorized as an operator.', width=110).pack()
    Label(page2, text='FAILURE TO FOLLOW THIS POLICY MAY RESULT IN IMMEDIATE TERMINATION OF EMPLOYMENT', fg='red').pack()
    Label(page2, text='', width=110).pack()
    Label(page2, text='Once again, it is very important to follow all safety precautions and notices.  Failure to do so can result in one or more of the following:', width=110).pack()
    Label(page2, text='*Severe burning', width=110).pack()
    Label(page2, text='*Severe damage to, or loss of, fingers', width=110).pack()
    Label(page2, text='*Temporary or permanent blindness', width=110).pack()
    Label(page2, text='*Minor to Severe damage to the Laser Cutter and/or its components', width=110).pack()
    Label(page2, text='', width=110).pack()
    Label(page2, text='On the next screen, you will see a list of precautions to follow.', width=110).pack()
    Label(page2, text='', width=110).pack()
    Label(page2, text='', width=110).pack()
    Label(page2, text='...Click Previous to go Back, or Click Next to Continue...').pack(side = BOTTOM)
    page2.pack()

    page3 = Frame(wizIntro)
    Label(page3, text='', width=110).pack()
    Label(page3,  text='--Safety Precautions--', width=110).pack()
    Label(page3, text='', width=110).pack()
    Label(page3, text='1.  Do not look at the laser tube or at the laser strike-point without proper eyewear or through the glass on the Laser Cutter.', width=110).pack()
    Label(page3, text='2.  Do not attempt to overide the Door Safety Sensor to allow the laser to cut with the door open.', width=110).pack()
    Label(page3, text='3.  Keep hands clear of all moving parts and refrain from touching the mirrors with bare hands.', width=110).pack()
    Label(page3, text='4.  Do not make any adjustments to the laser calibration without proper training and authorization from your superviser.', width=110).pack()
    Label(page3, text='5.  Do not remove any covers except for the bottom-front (and only to empty the boxes behind said cover) without permission.', width=110).pack()
    Label(page3, text='6.  Keep a constant awareness and/or watch on the laser as it cuts, and cancel the cut-cycle as soon as problems occur,', width=110).pack()
    Label(page3, text='such as fires or when stamps catch on the Laser Head.', width=110).pack()
    Label(page3, text='7.  Report any problems that will cause the Laser Cutter to not operate properly to your supervisor immediately.', width=110).pack()
    Label(page3, text='Above all else, make safety your Highest Priority', width=110, fg='red').pack()
    Label(page3, text='', width=110).pack()
    Label(page3, text='...Click Previous to go Back, or Click Next to Continue...').pack(side = BOTTOM)
    page3.pack()

    page4 = Frame(wizIntro)
    Label(page4, text='', width=110).pack()
    Label(page4, text='...Click Previous to go Back, or Click Next to Continue...').pack(side = BOTTOM)
    page4.pack()

    #Commands:
    pages = [page1, page2, page3, page4]
    current = page1
    def move(dirn):
        nonlocal current
        idx = pages.index(current) + dirn
        if not 0 <= idx < len(pages):
            return
        current.pack_forget()
        current = pages[idx]
        current.pack(side = TOP)

    def nex():
        move(+1)

    def prev():
        move(-1)

    Button(wizIntro, text='Previous', command=prev).pack(side = LEFT)
    Button(wizIntro, text='Next', command=nex).pack(side = RIGHT)

    #End Code for the Introduction Wizard
```

Comment: Seems you're looking for the functionality of the [ttk.Notebook](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/tkinter.ttk.html#notebook) widget.

Comment: using a multitude of Label widgets seems like the long, hard way to do things. Have you considered using a single text widget? You can set the state to "disabled" after you insert the text so that the user can't type in it.

Comment: @BryanOakley, using a text widget is something I don't know how to do.  All I did was pull the wizard format in my app from a tutorial found at http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2005-May/038686.html.

Comment: @jdlunt0313: that example wasn't suggesting you use labels, it simply used a label as a placeholder. A text widget is a much better choice here because you only have one, and you can keep all the data for it in a string. It will be much easier to maintain.

Comment: oh ok.  I'll start migrating over to the text widget once I get more familiar with it.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason they all show up at once is because you're telling them to. Your code does this:

```
...
page1 = Frame(wizIntro)
...
page1.pack()
page2 = Frame(wizIntro)
...
page2.pack()
...
```

Every time you call `pack`, it places that widget on the screen. If you don't want them to appear at startup, don't call `pack` after creating each widget.

Comment: The problem with that is if I remove the calls, then no text shows up at all.  Would it be possible to call each pack in an "if" statement?  For example, if I code in "if current = page1():  page1.pack()"

Comment: @jdlunt0313: well, you have to pack the very first one. After that, it looks like your "move" code packs the next one.

Comment: that hit the spot.  Thank you